# How to add custom data in order payment extension attribute rest api in magento2

Tags: sales-order, magento-2.1.7, rest-api

I want to add custom data in order payment extension attribute like below :-

```
"payment": {
                "account_status": null,
                "additional_information": [
                    "Credit Card",
                    "M",
                    "M",
                    "I",
                    "FXZDM9",
                    "1000",
                    "Approved",
                    "xxxx-1111",
                    "Visa"
                ],
                "amount_authorized": 31.9,
                "amount_ordered": 31.9,
                "amount_paid": 31.9,
                "base_amount_authorized": 31.9,
                "base_amount_ordered": 31.9,
                "base_amount_paid": 31.9,
                "base_amount_paid_online": 31.9,
                "base_shipping_amount": 9.95,
                "base_shipping_captured": 9.95,
                "cc_exp_month": "12",
                "cc_exp_year": "2030",
                "cc_last4": "1111",
                "cc_trans_id": "m4ybzfr7",
                "cc_type": "VI",
                "entity_id": 70659,
                "last_trans_id": "m4ybzfr7",
                "method": "braintree",
                "parent_id": 80005,
                "shipping_amount": 9.95,
                "shipping_captured": 9.95,
                "extension_attributes": {
                    "vault_payment_token": {
                        "entity_id": 34386,
                        "customer_id": 76756,
                        "public_hash": "f0ad9e74cc52a78f499d318ee9e55fb479b0a757dbecb10849fbf960a5e84c5b",
                        "payment_method_code": "braintree",
                        "type": "card",
                        "created_at": "2017-11-15 13:20:54",
                        "expires_at": "2031-01-01 00:00:00",
                        "gateway_token": "7jfdwj",
                        "token_details": "{\"type\":\"VI\",\"maskedCC\":\"1111\",\"expirationDate\":\"12\\/2030\"}",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "is_visible": false
                    }
                "custom_data": {
                        "key1" => "value1",
                         "key2" => "value2"
                  }
                }
            },
```

as above you can see, I want to add this

```
"custom_data": {
                        "key1" => "value1",
                         "key2" => "value2"
                  }
```

I have no idea how to do it, can anyone suggest me ?

Comment: you need to use extension attribute for that

Answer (score 2):

`Magento\Vault\Plugin\PaymentVaultAttributesLoad` should be your friend here, this is essentially doing what you want to do. It's worth looking into this module.

You will need to do the following:

- Create a new `extension_attribute` via your modules `etc/extension_attributes.xml` for the new payment information (useful docs here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html)
- Set your 'custom data' to the order payment entity (via an observer or plugin etc). You need to make sure this order payment data is saved. This may require adding a new field to the `sales_order_payment` table. **This step may not be required if the data is not order specific.**
- Create a plugin for `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentInterface` with method `afterGetExtensionAttributes`.

This plugin should essentially check the custom data is set to the order payment object, and if so, set it to the order payment as an extension attribute. Example below taken from `\Magento\Vault\Plugin\PaymentVaultAttributesLoad`

```
/**
 * Load vault payment extension attribute to order/payment entity
 *
 * @param OrderPaymentInterface $payment
 * @param OrderPaymentExtensionInterface|null $paymentExtension
 * @return OrderPaymentExtensionInterface
 */
public function afterGetExtensionAttributes(
    OrderPaymentInterface $payment,
    OrderPaymentExtensionInterface $paymentExtension = null
) {
    if ($paymentExtension === null) {
        $paymentExtension = $this->paymentExtensionFactory->create();
    }

    $paymentToken = $paymentExtension->getVaultPaymentToken();
    if ($paymentToken === null) {
        $paymentToken = $this->paymentTokenManagement->getByPaymentId($payment->getEntityId());
        if ($paymentToken instanceof PaymentTokenInterface) {
            $paymentExtension->setVaultPaymentToken($paymentToken);
        }
        $payment->setExtensionAttributes($paymentExtension);
    }

    return $paymentExtension;
}
```